# Regex for any non-zero number

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm using regex in Notepad++, recent version at time of post Nov 2016

I'm working on problem where I have dozens of text files containing financial information of wage and commission earnings. I need to find all employees that earned a commission

Files are formatted a such.

```
emp001smithj20150000095000
```

is an example of no commission earned last year (position 17, 5 chars = "00000")

```
emp002jonest20151752545000
```

is an example of $17525 commission earned last year (position 17, 5 chars = "17525")

**I've tried...**

```
^.{16}\b[1-9]{5}\b
```

The rationale is that I want any non-zero number among five character word boundary that starts at position 16, but no luck. I'm obviously missing something!

Comment: You may use `^.{16}[1-9]\d{4}` or `^.{16}(?!0{5})\d{5}`, but this will just let you find these values.

Comment: How can you be sure that each employee has a name with five characters?

Comment: @ Casimir et Hippolyte its the usernam. Yours would be 'hippoc' for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^.{16}(?!00000)
```

Use negative look around to find the next five characters that are not 00000

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use word boundaries here, as your numbers are surrounded by other numbers. You will need a lookahead to check, that your 5 digit number doesn't consist of numbers only, so a way would be:

```
^.{16}(?=0{0,4}[1-9])\d{5}
```

You shouldn't try to match `[1-9]{5}`, this e.g. won't match `15000`